# Prove that the following map is bounded from the given weighted $L^p$ space.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that the linear map  $T:L^1\left(\mathbb{R},(1+\lambda^2)^{-1}d\lambda\right)\to L^1\left(\mathbb{R},(1+\lambda^2)^{-2}d\lambda\right)$, given by  $T(f)(\lambda)=(1+\lambda^2)f(\lambda)-\int_{0}^{\lambda}xf(x)dx$, is bounded.

Comment: If someone shows that the Schwartz class functions are dense in the given weighted $L^p$ space, then the problem can be solved.

Comment: It's just Fubini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $T=T_1-T_2$, where $T_1f(\lambda)=(1+\lambda^2)f(\lambda)$. It's trivial that $T_1$ is bounded, and it seems like if $T_2$ *is* bounded this "must" be just Fubini, or more properly Tonelli:

Wlog $f\ge0$. Now $$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty(1+\lambda^2)^{-2} T_2f(\lambda)&=\int_0^\infty(1+\lambda^2)^{-2}
\int_0^\lambda xf(x)\,dxd\lambda
\\&=\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty(1+\lambda^2)^{-2}xf(x)\,d\lambda dx
\\&\le\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty(1+\lambda^2)^{-2}\lambda f(x)\,d\lambda dx
\\&=\frac12\int_0^\infty(1+x^2)^{-1}f(x)\,dx.\end{align}$$

Similarly for $\int_{-\infty}^0$; there  probably you want to start by rewriting $\int_0^\lambda=-\int_\lambda^0$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.. .

Comment: @CHANDANPRADHAN You might consider "accepting" the answer by clicking on the arrow...